# Rendering template won't work on heroku but works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, actionmailer

On my local machine, I can add a new user through a form and have rails send him an email. But on heroku, everything works until the part when the user has submitted the form and I am expecting to see something like the "welcome" page. That is the pages he's redirected to after registering.

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => ENV['myemail@gmail.com'],
   :password             => ENV['mypassword'],
   :authentication       => "plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true }
end
```

investors_controller.rb

```
class InvestorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #change from Investor.first!!!
    @investor = Investor.first
  end

  def show
    @investor = Investor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @investor = Investor.new
  end

  def create
    @investor = Investor.new(user_params)
    if @investor.save
        flash[:info] = "Welcome, you're now on your way to success!"
        render "/static_pages/welcome"
      InvestorMailer.welcome_email(@investor).deliver_now
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @investor.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Updated"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:investor).permit(:name, :email, :country,
                                   :phone)
    end
end
```

From the controller after an `Investor` is created, I render a template. That template shows fine on localhost but not on heroku.

I have tried `heroku pg:reset` but can't seem to find how to fix it. This is my heroku logs.

```
2015-06-11T11:47:21.908239+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:47:21.908239+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:22.979153+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, SECRET_KEY_BASE, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES config vars by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:22.979153+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:23.395722+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE resource by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:23.395722+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:23.621173+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:23.717284+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-06-11T11:51:23.717304+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-06-11T11:51:23.662060+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 12cea55 by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:23.662060+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:51:26.894425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 29521 -e production`
2015-06-11T11:51:30.475571+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-06-11 11:51:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-06-11T11:51:30.475610+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-06-11 11:51:30] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-06-11T11:51:30.475901+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-06-11 11:51:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=29521
2015-06-11T11:51:31.005422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-11T11:56:53.289790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=354682b8-2096-46ab-a299-8d04cbfa92a4 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=136ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-06-11T11:56:53.491368+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=ded548e3-4670-4f72-8f55-b7b77d334515 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-06-11T11:58:12.228820+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:create` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T11:58:16.855775+00:00 heroku[run.8863]: Awaiting client
2015-06-11T11:58:16.899503+00:00 heroku[run.8863]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:create`
2015-06-11T11:58:17.195573+00:00 heroku[run.8863]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-11T11:58:21.732727+00:00 heroku[run.8863]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-11T11:58:21.744351+00:00 heroku[run.8863]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-11T12:02:22.580784+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=fa00b3d2-92af-45e1-a377-d07682730c57 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-06-11T12:02:33.888628+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-06-11T12:02:37.574303+00:00 heroku[run.8055]: Awaiting client
2015-06-11T12:02:37.632103+00:00 heroku[run.8055]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-06-11T12:02:37.950399+00:00 heroku[run.8055]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-11T12:02:42.809261+00:00 heroku[run.8055]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-11T12:02:42.795864+00:00 heroku[run.8055]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-11T12:02:48.465779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=b335d5c3-6057-4f55-83ff-7852c60043eb fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=1506
2015-06-11T12:02:48.665596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=3850955a-f544-462c-bb56-659cf2a37004 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=212
2015-06-11T12:02:49.142636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-b598aa7e82e5647cd54ae6f409306995766dd0ce1af586bab9ebe84804d0eec0.js" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=aaa58ef4-4c05-467b-aeed-0c61755fc492 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=201ms status=200 bytes=117764
2015-06-11T12:03:04.152723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/investors/new" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=2573afdc-9a0a-4aab-a4ca-83215653cb4f fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=2207
2015-06-11T12:03:14.390979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/investors" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=1a95c9bc-ea25-4a75-bc51-ef385a06c765 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=567ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-06-11T12:04:46.584140+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/investors" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=661e547b-f2b9-459b-a15c-e4aca2a3fa16 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=322ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-06-11T12:04:52.175142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=9c97165a-fad1-453c-9902-2ea72a63f393 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=1506
2015-06-11T12:04:52.349183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=d1d85822-b7d2-49f6-b4a7-aab4640f9efc fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-06-11T12:04:52.636697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-b598aa7e82e5647cd54ae6f409306995766dd0ce1af586bab9ebe84804d0eec0.js" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=f12ec67a-29c2-494a-90c8-2fced158045b fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-06-11T12:04:57.447980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/investors/new" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=8300be1c-136c-4595-aaa3-fcbec763358f fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=2207
2015-06-11T12:05:10.874873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/investors" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=5d322cae-1009-4a4a-b586-acbc1a1bb0be fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=308ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-06-11T12:07:25.348309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=f45225d8-d1d9-4c2a-95e6-bbdb589ee80b fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=1506
2015-06-11T12:07:25.516873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=8995aed0-688e-4f4f-87cb-fb32dd61bfb0 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-06-11T12:07:25.803024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-b598aa7e82e5647cd54ae6f409306995766dd0ce1af586bab9ebe84804d0eec0.js" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=2b6eefdf-6e08-40cd-bbdc-9eddbb00b375 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-06-11T12:07:56.107177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/investors/new" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=f3ff502c-1a21-43bd-95ec-0557b63f83bc fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=2207
2015-06-11T12:08:04.826779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/investors" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=75971fd1-c059-4185-95e2-5d4e7a769366 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=314ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Comment: I've had issues with Heroku and asset precompilation, if that's the case [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) might prove useful

Comment: "That template shows fine on localhost but not on heroku...."  is not descriptive. What do you see on heroku after the user submits the form: a blank page, a 500 server error, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST to /investors/new is raising a 500 error:

```
2015-06-11T12:05:10.874873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/investors" host=infinite-oasis-2303.herokuapp.com request_id=5d322cae-1009-4a4a-b586-acbc1a1bb0be fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=308ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

My *guess* is this is something to do with the InvestorMailer...  I'd check the configuration for that and ensure that is sending as my first steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the leading slash from "/static_pages/welcome". Heroku may be blocking that as a potential security exploit.

Comment: that doesn't fix it in my case.

Comment: I'm curious why you're not seeing a more detailed error message from Heroku. Do you have the 12factor gem installed?

Comment: i didn't have that gem. just installed it. committed and pushed to heroku, same error, same logs. i'm also a bit surprised why heroku logs is not giving any useful info, in cases like this i have no idea what to do.

Comment: Have you run the migrations on Heroku?

Comment: unless `heroku run rake db:migrate` is wrong, i have run it.